# Nippy conure wants lots of affection

Tags: training, biting, parrots

I am dealing with a bit of a paradox in my green cheek Conure. She constantly wants to be in contact me and is very affectionate, but nips constantly whenever my hands go near her to move her, get her to step up, or even pet her.

I am frustrated as I feel I must be reinforcing this behavior somehow and I am not sure how to extinguish it. I realize that when I want her to step-up she often doesn't want to leave my shoulder, or enjoys the "chase" if she is running around on a table.

Do I just need to reinforce the good behavior with treats each time I ask her to get on my finger? I have had a green cheek Conure in the past who was not nearly so nippy, so I am trying to figure out my new bird's personality and adjust my expectations and interactions with her. She is about 6 months old.